# React Native and Firebase ios build error "no visible @interface for X declares the selector X

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm using expo project to create ios app and when i create ios build i got the following two errors. I've been stuck on these errors for long time. I couldn't fine the solution for these errors.

```
❌  (node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/config/RNFirebaseRemoteConfig.m:52:86)

  50 | 
  51 | RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(enableDeveloperMode) {
> 52 |     FIRRemoteConfigSettings *remoteConfigSettings = [[FIRRemoteConfigSettings alloc] initWithDeveloperModeEnabled:YES];
     |                                                                                      ^ no visible @interface for 'FIRRemoteConfigSettings' declares the selector 'initWithDeveloperModeEnabled:'
  53 |     [FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig].configSettings = remoteConfigSettings;
  54 | }
  55 | 


❌  (node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/config/RNFirebaseRemoteConfig.m:87:51)

  85 |             rejecter:
  86 |             (RCTPromiseRejectBlock) reject) {
> 87 |     BOOL status = [[FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig] activateFetched];
     |                                                   ^ no visible @interface for 'FIRRemoteConfig' declares the selector 'activateFetched'
  88 |     resolve(@(status));
  89 | }
  90 |
```

These are my project versions:

```
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"expo": "~45.0.0",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6"

I'm using XCode 14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `react-native-firebase` dependency.

Instead, Please use `@react-native-firebase/remote-config` dependency.

I am not sure what features you implement with firebase, but `react-native-firebase` dependency didn't upgrade its version for 3 years.
So, there are a lot of conflicts.